# Непонятная синтаксическая ошибка, указывающая на двоеточие

Tags: python, pygame, синтаксис, python-3.10

[image: ошибка]
Изучая pygame, написал такой простенький код:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (156, 39, 176)
INDIGO = (63, 81, 181)
BLUE = (33, 150, 243)
GREEN = (76, 175, 80)
YELLOW = (255, 235, 59)
ORANGE = (255, 152, 0)
GREY = (158, 158, 158)

display = pygame.display.set_mode( (800, 600) )

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 400 
y = 300 

while True:
    display.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(display, BLUE, (x, y), 5)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            if event.button == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(display, ORANGE, (event.pos[0], event.pos[1]), 30)
            elif event.button == 3:
                pygame.draw.circle(display, WHITE, (event.pos[0], event.pos[1]), 30)
            elif event.button == 5:
                display.fill(BLACK)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        print('Левая стрелка')
        x -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        print('Правая стрелка')
        x += 10
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        print('Стрелка вверх')
        y -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        print('Стрелка вниз')
        y += 10


    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)
```

И собственно интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку на 31 строчке
(elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN : )
и указывает на двоеточие. Вроде всё правильно, сравнивал код с ресурсом, где я учился, копипастил, всё равно.

Может, связано с тем, что я перешёл на питон 3.10?

Comment: Какая конкретно синтаксическая ошибка? Приведите текст ошибки в вопросе.

Comment: Перед `:` пробела быть не должно

Comment: @AlexanderChernin этот пробел ни на что не влияет, это точно не является синтаксической ошибкой.

Comment: @insolor значит не угадал ) Хоть бы код ошибки...

Comment: Вот написано же - `Отступ вашего (elif) не соответствует никакому внешнему/прежнему уровню.` Скорее всего смешались отступы и пробелы

Comment: IndentationError - ошибка отступов. Такое могло бы быть, если бы у вас elif был не на одном уровне с if, но в коде в вопросе такой проблемы не видно. Но на всякий случай проверьте. Возможно какие-то спецсимволы идут в конце этой строки, так не понять.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin действительно, так и есть. Спасибо всем за решение проблемы!